External DVD reader won't read DVDs but reads CDs
I bought a Samsung External DVD Writer Model SE-S084D second hand in order to replace my older setup for reading and writing discs. The cable was missing so I bought a replacement one (male Mini-USB-B to double male USB-A) which was the same as the original. At first, I tried using a standard male Mini-USB-B to male USB-A cable but I wasn't able to read the DVD I tested so I've had assume that the optical drive was missing power and that I was needing a double USB-A cable.
Tested it today, I wasn't able to read DVDs but I managed to read CDs. So I tried some stuff hoping to solve the problem.
First, I obviously tried to make sure that the drivers were operational, and they are. Then, I tried plugging the power male USB-A to an outlet using an appropriate AC adaptor but the issue was still occurring. Finally, I tried running the optical drive on my MacBook but without success.
What's happening concretely: when I plug it without a disc, it gets recognized by Windows; when I insert a CD it reads it; when I insert a DVD it starts spinning then stops, gets disconnected from the computer then reconnects, starts spinning then stops, over and over.
I filmed what's happening using ImgBurn for you to understand better too so you can clearly see the issue: https://youtu.be/dnVt5RS1AVA
It's getting very infuriating, it's the third optical drive I'm trying to use normally.

Is it possible that your drive is for DVD-R and your disc is DVD+R, or vice-versa?

SE-S084D DVD requires two USB ports. What type of disk are you attempting to burn exactly?

@JeffZeitlin - It’s possible but unlikely

@Ramhound - Yeah, I'd agree under the circumstances that it's unlikely, and that there's something else going on. I only suggested it because I did get bit by that problem once.

For what it's worth, similar questions have been asked here and here; are you getting these as new (not returned/refurbished) from a reputable source, or from a cut-rate vendor?

@JeffZeitlin - I read the specifications for the drive. So I can definitely say, the drive should burn specific disks, but if it’s the type the author is using I cannot say.  The world surrounding optical DVD disks has changed in 14 years.

When those drives start not reading DVD media it suggests a failing laser, something quite expected in hardware of that vintage and used for who knows how long (more than a decade, perhaps?). If you payed more than US$5 for that you were scammed. You can find them new at Aliexpress for as low as US$12.

Thank you everyone for your answers and it clearly must be that the DVD laser is dead. I think I'll change for another one... for the fourth time lol. I don't think there's much to do.

The laser used for reading DVD is failing or completely dead.
